# Removing/Hiding scroll bars in Ubuntu applications

Tags: mac, scrollbar

I'm new to Ubuntu, coming from Mac OS. I love it so far, except for the very visible scrollbars on some of the programs I use. For instance, I'm using Notion daily, which looks like this on a mac:
[image: looks like this on a mac]

and like this in Ubuntu
[image: like this in Ubuntu].

Is there a way to hide scrollbars for any programs?

Thank you!

ps: Notion is not supported on Linux. I'm using this: (https://github.com/davidbailey00/notion-deb-builder/releases/tag/v2.0.6-windows)